# Xamarin iOS Could not AOT the assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Migration

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mono

We've added migrations to our xamarin forms project and ever since then we can't deploy it to an iOS device. It will run on the simulator fine but will fail with AOT errors on deploying to device.

It seems to be a fairly wide spread topic over the web but none of the ideas so far have made a difference. We're using EntityFrameworkCore v2.2.6 along with xamarin.forms v4.1.0.

I've tried adding the -v -v -v for more details on the build log but still just get:

```
Error       Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/MyUser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyCompany.Mobile.iOS/8fcd0a31c7f6e1a671890e2462fe729f/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/3-Build/MyCompany.Data.Persistence.dll'    MyCompany.Mobile.iOS
```

Any ideas what else I should try?

Comment: Are you by any chance using macOS Catalina?

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: @TimoSalomäki im running MacOS Mojave

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT have tried, deleting all my bins/obj, clean and rebuilds, reboots of both mac and windows box, rebooted the iOS device, added the -v -v -v monto touch arguments to check additional logs, I also removed the migration file from the project that as is failing and it no longer errored (but that file is needed), i just removed the migrations designer file and that worked so it looks like something in the designer file that AOT doesn't like.I also went to install the new xamarin ios interpreter to see if that fixes it but the visx failed to install.

Comment: Maybe, https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6700#issuecomment-519959628

Answer (score 1):

I haven't try these but it could fix your issue

- IOS Build -> General -> and uncheck the option Incremental Build.
- Disable LLVM.
- Remove all unnecesary classes, methods from your `MyCompany.Data.Persistence.dll` so it wont generate heavy code.
- Change Linking to Link All Assemblies

Comment: Incremental Build is already disabled along with LLVM. Changing the Linker Behaviour to Link All allows us to deploy to device but it starts causing other errors throughout the project with 3rd party dll's (telerik-UI)

Comment: What option have you selected in Linker `Sdk assemblies` or `Sdk and user assemblies`?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Android applications use a linker to reduce the size

The default value is **SdkOnly**

**None**: No linking will be attempted.

**SdkOnly**: Linking will be performed on the base class libraries only, not user's assemblies.

Full: Linking will be performed on base class libraries and user assemblies. For more details refer here.. Note: if you are facing an issue with linking such as
"GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: . Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

then recheck your xamarin.Android project settings and set the below tag,

true

It Should Solve Your Problem.